Verb conjugation of "run through"
This is a Google example sentence which uses run through (use or spend something recklessly or rapidly).

Her husband had long since run through her money.

Why is run through used in the example sentence? Should not ran through be used?

The three forms of run and come are.

Run, ran, run.
Come, came, come.


Ref. LSI Language Studies International site.
Verbs that have the same base form and past participle (but a different simple past form). For example:


The phrasal verb in the sentence is "had run through", which makes the sentence past perfect. Run is the past participle of the verb "to run". Normally you find the past participle form of the verb matching with the past form of the verb, but in case of "run", it matches with the base form of the verb.

Spell it out: had run through

Thank you sir! @Lambie

You still haven't done it and that chart helps nothing. And by the way, It's madam, not sir. :)

@Lambie Please clarify what you mean. I didn't understand whether you are addressing me or the OP.

How could I be addressing the OP? I am addressing you. Write it out clearly: had run through, so the OP can actually see it.

@Lambie I thought you found some mistake in my answer. The post had only one sentence in it and OP had understood the answer. I shall accept your suggestion and do it.

@Lambie What are you saying here, please? Though Thamilay seemed to get it, I have no idea what 'Spell it out: had run through…' might mean.
Can you spell it out?

@Lambie Thanks and why not say that in the first place? Either way, why not stick to one or the other, either 'spell out…' or 'spell it out…'
